# User details not storing in the SQL alchemy database , in Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, web, sqlalchemy

This is my code for retrieving user input from a /signup webpage and then storing it in a SQL Alchemy database

```
@app.route('/signup',methods=["GET","POST"])
def signup():
    if request.method == "POST":
        password = request.form['password']
        usr = user(username="Abhinav",email="C@demo.com",password=password)
        db.session.add(usr)
        db.session.commit()


    return render_template('signup.htm')
```

And this is what I get on the command line :(

```
    >>> user.query.all()
    []
    >>> user.query.all()
    []
    >>>
```

I am a beginner programmer learning Flask and Python and aiming to create an e-commerce site with the flask module, Please help me!

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: Some of these steps might shed more light on this issue: double check that you are performing a POST request, add logging (via print()) to check the status of each step. Maybe even have a separate route or template for the GET and POST paths so that you can see what logic is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're retrieving data from a Flask Form try adding `form.validate_on_submit()` to your route, where `SignupForm` is the name of the form.

```
@app.route('/signup',methods=["GET","POST"])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        password = request.form['password']
        usr = user(username="Abhinav",email="C@demo.com",password=password)
        db.session.add(usr)
        db.session.commit()


    return render_template('signup.htm')
```